# How to change font for the integral symbol

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I'm looking how to change the integral symbol.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[\int_a^b f(x) \mathrm{d} dx\]
\end{document}
```

I want to only change the font of `\int` to get a `\rm\int` like `\mathrm{d}` or can I  define a new `\rmint` using other package, for example `arev`?

```
\documentclass{article}
 %define a new command for \rm font of int

\begin{document}
\[\rmint_a^b \]
\end{document}
```

to get the style of `\int` is

[image]

---

I have get `\rmoint` and `\rmint` by

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rmintop}{\mathop}{rmlargesymbols}{82}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rmointop}{\mathop}{rmlargesymbols}{72}
```

but I can not get all of integrals as follows:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Importing a single symbol from a different font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/5764)

Comment: The commands you gave for the first integral longer work on my side, do you knows some other way of obtaining that font ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Define a new math font from a new font family besides the default `cmex`, for instance, `mdbch` and `euex`. Refer to `arevmath.sty`.

```
\documentclass{article}
%define a new command for \rm font of int
\DeclareSymbolFont{rmlargesymbols}{OMX}{mdbch}{m}{n}
% or \DeclareSymbolFont{rmlargesymbols}{U}{euex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rmintop}{\mathop}{rmlargesymbols}{82}
\newcommand{\rmint}{\rmintop\nolimits}
\begin{document}
$\rmint_a^b$
\[\rmint_a^b \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you use `\DeclareMathSymbol{\intop}...`, then `\int` will give the new symbol without any other intervention. With `amsmath` one may get wrong spacing with multiple integrals and so may need to modify `\intkern@` and `\intdots@`.

Comment: I'm trying to get this method to work with a different font, pxfonts. The reason for this is that I need both \int and \boldsymbol{\int} (which is not provided in the default). I don't need multiple integrals.

I can't understand what "82" is (I cannot even find the symbol \int in mdbch.sty...). Can anyone help me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a "complete" selection of "upright integrals" using the `mathdesign` fonts, suitably scaled. The part between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` has been taken from `amsmath.sty` and edited.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\def\upintkern@{\mkern-7mu\mathchoice{\mkern-3.5mu}{}{}{}}
\def\upintdots@{\mathchoice{\mkern-4mu\@cdots\mkern-4mu}%
 {{\cdotp}\mkern1.5mu{\cdotp}\mkern1.5mu{\cdotp}}%
 {{\cdotp}\mkern1mu{\cdotp}\mkern1mu{\cdotp}}%
 {{\cdotp}\mkern1mu{\cdotp}\mkern1mu{\cdotp}}}
\newcommand{\upiint}{\DOTSI\protect\UpMultiIntegral{2}}
\newcommand{\upiiint}{\DOTSI\protect\UpMultiIntegral{3}}
\newcommand{\upiiiint}{\DOTSI\protect\UpMultiIntegral{4}}
\newcommand{\upidotsint}{\DOTSI\protect\UpMultiIntegral{0}}
\newcommand{\UpMultiIntegral}[1]{%
  \edef\ints@c{\noexpand\upintop
    \ifnum#1=\z@\noexpand\upintdots@\else\noexpand\upintkern@\fi
    \ifnum#1>\tw@\noexpand\upintop\noexpand\upintkern@\fi
    \ifnum#1>\thr@@\noexpand\upintop\noexpand\upintkern@\fi
    \noexpand\upintop
    \noexpand\ilimits@
  }%
  \futurelet\@let@token\ints@a
}
\makeatother

\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{mdbch}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{mdbch}{m}{n}{ <->s * [0.8]  mdbchr7v }{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{mdbch}{b}{n}{ <->s * [0.8]  mdbchb7v }{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{mdbch}{bx}{n}{<->ssub * mdbch/b/n}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{uplargesymbols}{OMX}{mdbch}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{uplargesymbols}{bold}{OMX}{mdbch}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upintop}{\mathop}{uplargesymbols}{82}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upointop}{\mathop}{uplargesymbols}{"48}

\DeclareFontEncoding{MDB}{}{}
\DeclareFontFamily{MDB}{mdbch}{}
\DeclareFontShape{MDB}{mdbch}{m}{n}{ <->s * [0.8]  mdbchrmb }{}
\DeclareFontShape{MDB}{mdbch}{b}{n}{ <->s * [0.8]  mdbchbmb }{}
\DeclareFontShape{MDB}{mdbch}{bx}{n}{<->ssub * mdbch/b/n}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{MDB}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathdesignB}{MDB}{mdbch}{m}{n}%
\SetSymbolFont{mathdesignB}{bold}{MDB}{mdbch}{b}{n}%
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upintclockwise}{\mathop}{mathdesignB}{128}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upointclockwise}{\mathop}{mathdesignB}{130}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upointctrclockwise}{\mathop}{mathdesignB}{132}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upoiint}{\mathop}{mathdesignB}{134}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upoiiint}{\mathop}{mathdesignB}{136}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\upint}{\DOTSI\upintop\ilimits@}
\newcommand{\upoint}{\DOTSI\upointop\ilimits@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\upint_a^b\quad\int_a^b$ (for size comparison)

$\displaystyle\upint_a^b\quad\int_a^b$ (for size comparison)

$\displaystyle\upint\quad\upiint\quad\upiiint\quad\upidotsint$

$\displaystyle\upointclockwise\quad\upointctrclockwise\quad\upoint\quad\upoiint\quad\upoiiint$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Manuel Sorry, I introduced a bug with my last edit. Fix in a minute.

Comment: A new small problem, all the limits work well except in `\upiint`, `\upiiint` and (may be) `\upidotsint`. Try with this code: `\upiint_a^b\quad\upiiint_a^b\quad\upidotsint_a^b` (if you use `\limits` the `b` is not correctly positioned, and if you use `\nolimits` the `a` is not correctly positioned. Could you solve this?

Comment: Thank you! Can  we get it  by changing the  font of esint package? I have no  idea until now.

Comment: @Manuel When using `\limits` after multiple integrals only the lower limit makes sense and the code in `amsmath` is providing a centered lower limits; in my experiment the behavior with `\nolimits` seems correct.

Comment: @TeX.pig `esint` uses its own font, that consists only of integral symbols.

Comment: @egreg Okey, I don't know why, but the problem comes from using `\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}`. If you load the package with that option and then use `\limits` or `\nolimits` it works *bad*, as I said.

Comment: @Manuel As I said, multiple integrals really support only lower limits.

Comment: @egreg Yes, I agree with that, but WITHOUT `inlimits` option loaded. If you load it and use `\upiiint\nolimits_a^b` there is a problem with the sub `a`. But this is not truly related with the *change font* question.

Comment: @Manuel I see; but I don't see why one should set the `intlimits` option and use `\nolimits` for a *triple* integral.

Comment: Don't worry, I don't use it. Just wanted to get all right, as with `\upoiint` and `\upoiiint` the limits work pretty well.