# slender \lgroup and \rgroup

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

The default `\lgroup` symbol in the most of math-mode fonts is thicker as compared to the text- and math-mode alphabets and numbers. A few fonts provide slender `\lgroup` symbols like `newtxmath`, `mathabx`, `MnSymbol` (and may be others that I don't know). However, when I use any of this with XeLaTeX and fonts like STIX Two Text or Sitka Banner, I get "Too many font symbols declared". I just want to use `\lgroup` and `\rgroup` symbols from fonts that provide slender versions along with either STIX Two Text or Sitka Banner. The specific issue here is the location of chemmacros package. If you put this package before mathspec or \setallmainfonts, the code does not work.
Kindly respond.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{extbook}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in, bindingoffset = 0.4in, headsep = 5pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage[cmbraces, cmintegrals]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setallmainfonts[Scale=1.0, Numbers = {Lining, Proportional}]{Sitka Banner}


\begin{document}
\chapter{\LaTeXe}
\begin{align*}
\angle ABC &= \alpha \\
\dfrac{\cos\alpha}{\sin\beta} + \dfrac{\cos\beta}{\sin\alpha} &= 1  \\
\left\lgroup\dfrac{\dfrac{\cos^2\alpha}{\cos^2 \beta}}{\sin^2\beta} + \dfrac{\cos^2\beta}{\sin^2\alpha}\right\rgroup &= k \\
\left(\dfrac{\dfrac{\cos^2\alpha}{\cos^2 \beta}}{\sin^2\beta} + \dfrac{\cos^2\beta}{\sin^2\alpha}\right)&= k
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
I &=\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \dfrac{\cos^2 x}{\sin x} + \dfrac{\cos x}{\sin^2 x} \text{d}x \\
J &= \int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left\lgroup\dfrac{\cos^3 x}{\sin x} + \dfrac{\cos x}{\sin^3 x} \right\rgroup\text{d}x 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: lgroup isn't used very often but by intention it is a kind of thick bracket, why not use a standard `\left(` ?

Comment: The above runs with no error in xelatex, what exactly did you add that produced the too many math alphabets error?

Comment: It does work, it was chemmacros that causes an error. I have added that after mathspec. Sometimes, finding out error/bug in latex takes a lot of patience. One need to use lgroup, because for huge parentheses, normal (is not as beautiful, in my opinion. Thanks.

Comment: So, what I was looking for is, if I can exact code for lgroup and rgroup like \DeclareMathsymbol, that would saves lot of efforts. I am not aware of individual codes for lgroup & rgroup.

Comment: lgroup/rgroup are not (in most cases) parentheses as designed by the font designer they are simply the extendable `{` and `}` but not using the middle part. by default they are defined as follows although other font packages may have changed that \DeclareMathDelimiter{\lgroup} % extensible ( with sharper tips
     {\mathopen}{largesymbols}{"3A}{largesymbols}{"3A}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rgroup} % extensible ) with sharper tips
     {\mathclose}{largesymbols}{"3B}{largesymbols}{"3B}

Comment: Sorry, I am novice and don't understand much. If you can provide me something like \DeclareSymbolFont{rmlargesymbols}{OMX}{mdbch}{m}{n}
% or \DeclareSymbolFont{rmlargesymbols}{U}{euex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rmintop}{\mathop}{rmlargesymbols}{82} for \lgroup?

Comment: something on like this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88281/how-to-change-font-for-the-integral-symbol

Comment: no sorry I don't know that package (and you still haven't mentioned chemistry in your question) I suggest you edit your question so that it actually describes your problem, then someone knowing the package should see it. Although I think using lgroup here is wrong basically using ( is semantically better and what 99% of tex documents would use for such matrices

Comment: Basically, I am preparing assignments/exercises in Physics, Chemistry and Maths. The preamble that I used was working for Maths did not work for chemistry. Thanks for your time. lgroup is required in physics/maths, The sample code is mentioned. Thanks so much for your efforts.

Comment: lgroup is not only meant for matrices. In Maths, {} and [] have special meaning attached to them, so the only choices remain are \lgroup and (). As a practice, one does not use two types of braces in the same expression.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments?!