# Slim big parentheses (around a matrix)

Tags: math-mode, matrices, brackets, bigdelim

When typesetting formulas with matrices, I have a difficulty choosing between parentheses and brackets. The usual parentheses look too wide, waste horizontal space, and do not highlight the matrix rectangular shape. The brackets can confuse the reader because I use brackets for other things too, and they disagree with how I write formulas on a blackboard (parentheses are easier to draw).

How can I have some kind of slim parentheses around a matrix, that are almost like brackets, but with rounded ends?

---

Related questions:

- [How to make large brace and parenthesis thinner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/453436)
- [slender \lgroup and \rgroup](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/478685)

Comment: lgroup and rgroup ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks, that may be it. Is there some predefined environment to get matrices with `\lgroup`/`\rgroup`?

Comment: `\newenvironment{gmatrix}{\left\lgroup\env@matrix}{\endmatrix\right\rgroup}` inside a .sty or \makeatletter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `lgroup` `\rgroup` (which are `{}` without the middle bits) or use an extended delimiter from a smaller font

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{gmatrix}{\left\lgroup\env@matrix}{\endmatrix\right\rgroup}
\newenvironment{xpmatrix}{\bgroup\scriptscriptstyle\left(\bgroup\displaystyle\env@matrix}{\endmatrix\egroup\right)\egroup}\makeatother
\begin{document}


\[X+\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}+Y\]
\[X+\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}+Y\]
\[X+\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}+Y\]
\[X+\begin{xpmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{xpmatrix}+Y\]
\[X+\begin{gmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{gmatrix}+Y\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I wonder if I could also have starred versions like `pmatrix*`, where I can specify the alignment, like `[r]`.

Comment: @Alexey I rolled back the edit, the code is repeated but it matches the image shown (could remake that of course) , I copied the amsmath versions if you copy the mathtools `pmatrix*` in the smame way you will get `*` versions of these,

Comment: Copying definition from `mathtools` turned out not to be easy: it is in a `.dtx` file which I am not familiar with, and it uses command names like "`\MT_matrix_begin:N`", which cannot be read by `latex` without some tweaks.

Comment: Will there be any adverse effects if instead of copying definitions, I build upon plain matrix environments? Like this: `\newenvironment{mmatrix}{\left\lgroup\begin{matrix}}{\end{matrix}\right\rgroup}`,
`\newenvironment{mmatrix*}[1][c]{\left\lgroup\begin{matrix*}[#1]}{\end{matrix*}\right\rgroup}`.

Comment: @Alexey you lose the extra negative space between the delimiter and matrix but that may not be optimal anyway for these