# How to use package euler for only the integral symbol?

Tags: symbols, euler

Is there a way to use only the symbol from the integral of the package `euler` without loading the whole package?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font could help

Comment: or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88281/how-to-change-font-for-the-integral-symbol?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the modern toolchain, with `unicode-math`, you can download the Neo Euler font and write:

```
\setmathfont[range = {\int, \oint}, Scale = MatchUppercase]{euler.otf}
```

With the legacy type 1 fonts, look up the symbol in appendix D of [the `amsfonts` manual.](http://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/fonts/amsfonts/doc/amsfndoc.pdf)  The `\int` symbol is in the font `euex`, and we see that the display-style `\int` is in slot `"5A` and the text-style `\int` in slot `"52`.  Therefore, we can load this font as a math alphabet and select the appropriate style using `\mathchoice`.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\DeclareSymbolFont{eulerex}{U}{euex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\big@int}{\mathop}{eulerex}{"5A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\little@int}{\mathop}{eulerex}{"52}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\int}[0]{\mathchoice%
{\big@int}%
{\little@int}%
{\little@int}%
{\little@int}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\( \displaystyle\int\ldots \) \\
\( \textstyle\int\ldots \) \\
\( \int_{\int_{\int}} \ldots \)
\end{document}
```

[image: Euler integrals]

And likewise for `\oint` if you need it.